# UITextField no longer has the function distinctUntilChanged()

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, rx-cocoa

Since upgrading to Swift 3 with pod **'RxSwift', '~> 3.0'** and **'RxCocoa', '~> 3.0'**, it seems that ***distinctUntilChanged()*** is no longer available for *UITextField*. I want to use it as below. Do I need to write and extension for *UITextField* or am I missing something since the update from Swift 2?

```
 textField.rx.text.distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(onNext: {text in print("\(text)")}
```

Comment: I think this can be traced down to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/626).

Comment: Yes it seems you might be right. I will reevaluate our use-cases and see if they are really required. Thanks for the input.